# Configure starting index of StatefulSet's pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

#### As we all know from the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#ordinal-index):

> For a StatefulSet with N replicas, each Pod in the StatefulSet will be assigned an integer ordinal, from 0 up through N-1, that is unique over the Set.

#### Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-np
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-np
spec:
  serviceName: zoo-svc-np
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper-np
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper-np
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: zookeeper-np
        image: zookeeper:3.5.6
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30005
        - containerPort: 30006
        - containerPort: 30007
        env:
        - name: ZOO_MY_ID
          value: "1"
```

The above manifest will create three pods like below:

```
NAME                     READY   STATUS    STARTS   AGE
pod/zookeeper-np-0       1/1     Running   0        203s
pod/zookeeper-np-1       1/1     Running   0        137s
pod/zookeeper-np-2       1/1     Running   0        73s
```

#### Question:

Is there a way to configure this starting index (0) to start from any other integer (e.g 1,2,3 etc.)?

For example, to start the above pod indices from 3 so that the pods created will look like something below:

```
NAME                     READY   STATUS    STARTS   AGE
pod/zookeeper-np-3       1/1     Running   0        203s
pod/zookeeper-np-4       1/1     Running   0        137s
pod/zookeeper-np-5       1/1     Running   0        73s
```

Or if there is only one replica of the statefulset, its ordinal is not zero but some other integer (e.g **12**), so that the only pod created will be named as ***pod/zookeeper-np-12***?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible, according to [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/12f36302f9ee98093d0a01910e345825f1d3a86e/pkg/controller/statefulset/stateful_set_control.go) 0...n is just slice index of replicas slice. See the last argument to `newVersionedStatefulSetPod`

Comment: Is there any way to configure the pod name in case there is only one replica? I am looking for this because deploying [incubator/kafka](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/kafka) Helm chart configures the brokerID from the last letter of the pod-name. See [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/cc7e5d7aeb78a85f3b73d1e1229196d0334de4a4/incubator/kafka/templates/statefulset.yaml#L201). Is there any way to somehow change the last digit of the pod name in order to manually configure the broker ID?

Comment: StatefulSets will have a number at the end. No matter fo what, that's how they work. I think it's better to raise an issue on Kafka chart and provide solution on it.

Comment: I get that. Makes sense. I will edit the question and add the link to the issue once created.